# Kusto query for checking that certain tag does NOT exist

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm building a Kusto query for Azure Resource Graph that will return me all items for which a specific tag does NOT exist. What would be the query for checking this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the tags are represented in the table's schema.

- If they are all in a single string (separated by one or more characters), then use `where Tags !has "UnwantedTag"`
- If they are stored in a dynamic column, then use `where set_has_element(Tags, "UnwantedTag") == false`

Answer (score -1):

found the solution:
if we want it to have the tag
'| where tags contains'
if we don't want it to have the tag
'| where tags !contains'

Comment: `!contains` isn't suitable for this case, as you want to check for a specific full word, so `!has` is better here as it utilizes Kusto's index, and will make the query much more performant. `contains` should only be used when looking for substrings that are not full tokens. See more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datatypes-string-operators#performance-tips  -  I suggest to delete this answer.